# PROBLEMA AL RECIBIR DATOS DESDE FORMULARIO CON POST Y GET

Tags: array, post, get, undefined

Hola tengo un problema al recibir datos por método post y get en php, ya que por medio de URL estoy pasando datos a otro fichero .php, hasta el momento, por GET si funciona, sin embargo, al intentar recibir datos por medio de POST, no define el valor del formulario
Error:
Warning: Undefined array key "causa" in C:\xampp\htdocs\CivicForms\authordenny.php on line 9

Cabe mencionar, que ya intenté cambiar el metodo en el formulario a GET

**Formulario.php**

```php
    <?php
    include("header.php");
    $id=(isset($_GET['idPeticion'])?$_GET['idPeticion']:"");
?>
<title>PETICIÓN <?php echo $id; ?> </title>
<header id="header" class="hoc clear"> 
    <div id="comments">
        <center> <h2>PETICIÓN: <?php echo $id;?></h2></center>
        <?php
                $sql="SELECT * FROM peticiones WHERE ID_Peticion='$id'";
                $datos=$dbx->GetAll($sql);
                foreach($datos as $key => $value){
                    $municipio=$value["Municipio"];
                    $Dia=$value["Dia"];
                    $mes=$value["Mes"];
                    $anio=$value["Anio"];
                    $tipo=$value["TipoPeticion"];//consultar a BD
                    $requerimiento=$value["Requerimento"];
                    $idsolicitante=$value["ID_Solicitante"];
                    $oficina=$value["ID_Oficina"];
                    $documentacion=$value["Documentacion"];
                    $status=$value["Status"];
                }
                $tipo=$dbx->GetOne("SELECT Tipo FROM tipospeticiones WHERE ID_Peticion='$tipo'");
                $office=$dbx->GetOne("SELECT Nombre_Oficina FROM oficinas WHERE ID_Oficina='$oficina'");
                $datos2=$dbx->GetAll("SELECT * FROM ciudadanos WHERE ID_Ciudadano='$idsolicitante'");
                foreach($datos2 as $key => $value){
                    $nameuser=$value["Nombre"]." ".$value["ApellidoP"]." ".$value["ApellidoM"];
                }
            ?>
        
        <form action="authordenny.php" method="POST">
            <label>FOLIO: </label>
            <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>">
            <label>TIPO DE PETICIÓN: </label>
            <input type="text" name="type" value="<?php echo $tipo;?>" readonly>
            <label>REQUERIMIENTO: </label>
            <textarea readonly> <?php echo $requerimiento;?></textarea>
            <label>SOLICITANTE: </label>
            <input type="text" name="solicitante" value="<?php echo $nameuser;?>" readonly>
            <label>FECHA: </label>
            <input type="text" name="fecha" value="<?php echo $Dia." DE ".$mes." DEL ".$anio;?>" readonly>
            <label>OFICINA DE DESTINO: </label>
            <input type="text" name="office" value="<?php echo $office?>" readonly>
            <label>ESTATUS: </label>
            <input type="text" name="sts" value="<?php echo $status?>" readonly>
            <label>CAUSA DE RECHAZAR BAJA</label>
            <br>
            <center>
            <h2>DOCUMENTACIÓN CARGADA</h2>
            <!-- MOSTRAR DOCUMENTACIÓN-->
            <?php
                $thefolder = $documentacion;
                if ($handler = opendir($thefolder)) {
                    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handler))) {
                        if($file=="." || $file==".."){
                            $file=null;
                        }
                        echo "<a href='$documentacion$file'target='_blank'> $file</a><br>";
                    }
                    closedir($handler);
                }?>
                <?php
                if($status=="RECHAZADA" || $status=="APROBADA"){
                    echo"
                        <br>
                        <input type='submit' name='aprobar' value='APROBAR PETICIÓN' disabled ><br><br>
                        <input type='submit' name='rechazar' value='RECHAZAR PETICIÓN' disabled >
                    ";
                }else{//para pasar multiples variables por URL se coloca &var=$var
                    echo"
                        <label>CAUSA DE RECHAZAR BAJA</label>
                        <input type='text' name='causa' id='url'>
                        <p>En caso de rechazar, es necesario la causa</p>
                        <br>
                        <a href=authordenny.php?accion=auth&idPeticion=$id&idsol=$idsolicitante&office=$oficina class='btn btn-success'>AUTORIZAR PETICIÓN</a> <br><br>
                        <a href=authordenny.php?accion=denny&idPeticion=$id class='btn btn-success'>RECHAZAR PETICIÓN</a> <br>
                    ";
                }
            ?><br><br>
            
        </form>
        </center>
        <br>
        <a href="index.php"><input type="button" value="REGRESAR" /></a>
    </div>
</header>
<?php
    include("footer.php");
?>
```

**authordenny.php**
En este fichero comenté la línea 8, ya que con esta línea no aparece el error, y al imprimir la variable para ver si se obtuvo es " ".

```php
    <?php
    include("header.php");
    //obtiene valores pasados por URL
    $id=(isset($_GET['idPeticion'])?$_GET['idPeticion']:"");
    $accion = (isset($_GET['accion'])?$_GET['accion']:"");
    $user = (isset($_GET['idsol'])?$_GET['idsol']:"");
    $oficina = (isset($_GET['office'])?$_GET['office']:"");
    //$causa = (isset($_POST['causa'])?$_POST['causa']:"");
    $causa=$_POST['causa']
?>
<title>PETICIÓN <?php echo $id; ?> </title>
<header id="header" class="hoc clear"> 
    <div id="comments">
        <?php
            switch($accion){
                case "auth":
                    $sql="UPDATE peticiones SET `Status` = 'APROBADA' WHERE ID_Peticion='$id'";
                    $package=($dbx->GetOne("SELECT MAX(Paquete) AS Paquete From logistica"))+1;
                    $sql2="INSERT INTO `logistica` (`ID_traking`, `Paquete`, `ID_Peticion`, `Origen`, `Destino`, `Ruta`, `Status`, `Checkpoint`, `Conductor`, `Entrego`) VALUES (NULL, '$package','$id', 'NULL', $oficina, 'NULL', 'PENDIENTE DE PROCESAMIENTO', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL')";  
                break;
                case"denny":
                    echo $causa;
                    //$sql="UPDATE peticiones SET `Status` = 'RECHAZADA',`CRechazada` = '$causa' WHERE ID_Peticion='$id'";
                    //$datosx=$dbx->Execute($sql);
                    echo"<h2>SE HA RECHAZADO LA PETICIÓN</h2>";
                break;

            }
            
        ?>
        
    </div>
</header>
<?php   

    include("footer.php");
    
?>
```

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 TL;DR: Copia código y pega código, con imágenes de código disminuyes notablemente la ayuda que puedas recibir. Saludos.

Comment: Primero deberías de poner el código en texto aquí en la pregunta para que podamos hacer pruebas, después decirte que hay algo que no me cuadra, le estas poniendo un link al formulario para que te haga la petición por GET pero si quieres que haga la petición por post deberías de hacer el submit del formulario.

Aparte estas haciend `$_POST["causa"]` cuando deberias de hacer `$_POST["Cada name de los inputs del form"]`